# Equivalent of beamerboxesrounded for rectangles inner theme

Tags: beamer

I have some blocks which don't have a title and I am having some difficulties formatting them. If I use an ordinary block with an empty title, then the header is still visible. If I use a `beamercolorbox`, then the format of the block differs from the ordinary blocks. A `beamerboxesrounded` seems to work okay, except that I am using the `rectangles` inner theme, so I would like something equivalent for this theme.

Below is a small example illustrating the issue.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>

\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\useoutertheme{split}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{title}
body
\end{block}

\begin{block}{}
body without title
\end{block}

\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth,sep=1em]{block body}
body without title (notice different size)
\end{beamercolorbox}

\begin{beamerboxesrounded}{}
body without title (this size looks OK)
\end{beamerboxesrounded}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Issue with boxes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Below I present two options:

1. More a hack than a real solution, but can be useful for a one-time situation: use a negative space in the title, as in

   ```
   \begin{block}{\vspace{-1.5ex}}
   body without title
   \end{block}
   ```
2. You can define a block that handles the case of no title appropriately. Below I did this by defining a template similar to `block begin` but with no title and then using this template to define a `ntblock`.

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>

\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\useoutertheme{split}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

%template for block without title
\defbeamertemplate{block begin}{notitle}
{
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}

\newenvironment<>{ntblock}
  {\setbeamertemplate{block begin}[notitle]
  \begin{block}#1{}}
  {\end{block}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{title}
body
\end{block}

\begin{block}{\vspace{-1.5ex}}
body without title
\end{block}

\begin{block}{title}
body
\end{block}

\begin{ntblock}
body without title
\end{ntblock}

\begin{block}{title}
body
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```